# Set value Dynamic action error: Ajax call returned server error ORA-20987: APEX - ERR-1002 Unable to find item ID

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a master detail form in Oracle APEX. The detail table has items: ID, NAME, PRICE, VAT, TOTAL_COST. I wanted to make items VAT and TOTAL_COST automatically filled up and displayed based on the entered value in the field of PRICE. I have made 2 dynamic actions (set value) on the item PRICE: one for VAT and other for TOTAL_COST.

SQL Statement for the VAT dynamic action (Items to submit: PRICE; Affected Elements: VAT):

`select (0.25 * :PRICE) VAT from DUAL`

SQL Statement for the TOTAL_COST dynamic action (Items to submit: PRICE,VAT; Affected Elements: TOTAL_COST):

`select (:PRICE + :VAT ) TOTAL_COST from DUAL`

But when I enter a value in app for PRICE it returns me an error:

"Ajax call returned server error ORA-20987: APEX - ERR-1002 Unable to find item ID for item "C6658462655450231454" in application "127893". - Unexpected error, unable to find item name at application or page level. for ."

Comment: Looks like you're referencing an item which doesn't exist on the page.

Comment: But I'm not, it was working on some other app, but now it's not working

Comment: Either you're misinterpreting reality, or Apex isn't  telling the truth (i.e. you found bug). The fact that it worked on **some other application** doesn't mean that it works in this one. Unfortunately. Did you try to run page in debug mode and - after it raises an error - review debug data? It might tell you what went wrong.

Comment: I did, but I can't interpret anything from it.

Comment: I strongly suggest using the apex naming convention for page items. P<page_number>_NAME, eg P1_VAT, P1_PRICE. It will make your life as a developer a lot easier.

Comment: This is master detail form, so items have P<number>_ITEM, but these are columns (detail report page)